# Adapt wagtail tag filter to include an operator so multiple tags can be searched

Tags: python, django, search, tags, wagtail

I have a working search form on my Wagtail template that finds pages based on their tags but as there is no operator (`AND` or `OR`) only one tag can be searched at a time.

Can someone advise me how I would adapt this code to allow for multiple tag searches?

**models.py**

```
    tag_posts = PostsPage.objects.live().public().order_by('-first_published_at')


    if request.GET.get('tag', None):
        tags = request.GET.get('tag')
        tag_posts = tag_posts.filter(tags__slug__in=[tags])

        # Paginate all posts by 2 per page
        paginator = Paginator(tag_posts, 2)

        # Try to get the ?page=x value
        page = request.GET.get("page")
        try:
            posts = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            posts = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context["posts"] = tag_posts

        return context
```

**search_page.html**

```
            <form role="search" method="get" class="form-search" action="posts" method="get">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control search-query" name="tag" placeholder="What are you after?" title="Search for:" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="" id="searchsubmit" value="">
                        <span class="btn btn-default">GO</span>
                      </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to allow users to enter multiple tags separated by commas (or any other separator character(s) of your choice).  The below code allows for commas, semicolons and vertical bars to be used as separators.  It does not use white space as a separator since taggit's tags can be more than one word.

I would change:

```
tag_posts = PostsPage.objects.live().public().order_by('-first_published_at')

if request.GET.get('tag', None):
    tags = request.GET.get('tag')
    tag_posts = tag_posts.filter(tags__slug__in=[tags])
```

to:

```
tag_string = request.GET.get('tag', None)
if tag_string:
    tags = re.split('[,;|]', tag_string.lower())
    tag_ids = Tag.objects.annotate(name_lower=Lower('name')).filter(name_lower__in=tags).values_list('id', flat=True)
    tag_posts = PostsPage.objects.live().public().filter(tags__in=tag_ids).order_by('-first_published_at')
```

Note that the above selects case-insensitively by tag name, not slug value.

Also do:

```
import re
from django.db.models.function import Lower
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response Dan. I've tried your suggestion but I'm getting no results now I'm afraid (also made sure to import re). Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer Dan, I can now use the search to add multiple tags, as long as I use commas and no spaces. However, I need a way of removing the whitespace and adding the comma automatically, otherwise users will get no results. Do you think this is possible, or will I have to rethink my approach and maybe use haystack / elasticsearch?